# Ajax technique used by popular sites such as facebook

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I'm interested in using a similar ajax technique that facebook uses. For instance, at your home page when you click on a group on the side it loads the content in the main section but does not have to re-render the top dash or side components. I've messed around with partial views and loading them at request but it's still not the same because it does not seem like an "action" and thus it doesn't change the url and the back button will only take you back from your previous action, not from the partial view.

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a tutorial or reference that goes over this technique for ASP.NET MVC 4.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: they are using html 5 history API http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history'

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! When using asp.net would you say once the state has been pushed to load a partial view into the main content area?

Comment: dont understand. try rephrasing...

Comment: I think you're after a SPA (Single Page Application) style approach to web development checkout this blog here for a run down http://www.asp.net/single-page-application also here http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159 and http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/ and finally here http://durandaljs.com/

Comment: To build a web UI that is facebook similar you need a powerful JavaScript client GUI library , the server side technologies like MVC3/4 ASP.NET will not help here.

check the sencha extjs library here:http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

for an overview of most popular JS GUI libraries check this: http://javascriptlibraries.com/

Comment: Thanks for the great information guys, I've looked through all of the techniques you've linked me and have learnt a lot. I think what best applies to my application is the SPA approach but I really appreciate all of the other comments and help

Answer (score 0):

To build a web UI that is facebook similar you need a powerful JavaScript client GUI library , the server side technologies like MVC3/4 ASP.NET will not help here.

check the sencha extjs library here:http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

for an overview of most popular JS GUI libraries check this: http://javascriptlibraries.com/